# Insert value to URL path

Tags: php, str-replace, request-uri

I have a site with content that is different for market locations, so I am setting a cookie for the users location. If a user tries going to a landing page directly I would like to insert the market location to the URL.

For example, if a user tries going to `www.mysite.com/packages` I would like to update the URL to be `www.mysite.com/tampa/packages`

I have a cookie set called "market", and this is the code I am trying, but it isn't working.

```
<?php
switch ($_COOKIE['market']) {

  case "tampa":
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    switch (true) { 
      case strstr($url, 'packages'):
        $currenturl = str_replace('/packages','/tampa/packages/',$url);
        return $currenturl;
        break;
    }
    break;

  // etc for other markets
}
```

Is PHP the right approach for this? Is there a better solution that would work? Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to reload the webpage with the new URL like so:

Instead of:

```
return $currenturl;
```

Do:

```
Header('Location: '.$currenturl);
```

Be sure there's no output to the browser before doing so though.

Comment: I'm sure this is the correct solution, I'm using the MODX CMS, so I just need to figure out another line to add like `echo $modx->sendRedirect("$currenturl", array('type' => 'REDIRECT_HEADER'));` (I had to do something similar when I set another header() to set cookie). Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you need by `figure out another line`?

Comment: For example, when I set my cookies I had to write my code like `case 'Tampa':
        $ip_market = 'tampa';
        header("Set-Cookie: market=$ip_market; Path=/; Expires=".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T',time()+720*60*60));
        echo $modx->sendRedirect('tampa/',array('type' => 'REDIRECT_HEADER'));
        break;`